# BlueprintJS: Modify the width of a Tooltip component

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, popover, blueprintjs

I'm using the React Blueprint library. I have a tooltip that contains a relatively long piece of content:

```
                  <Tooltip
                    className={Classes.TOOLTIP_INDICATOR}
                    content={
                      "This is a pretty long tooltip. Long enough that it should probably be wrapped."
                    }
                    position={Position.RIGHT}
                  >
                    Tooltip
                  </Tooltip>
```

Is it possible to either control the width of the tooltip or cause the text to wrap? The documentation doesn't contain props that would suggest this is possible. Is it just better to use a Popover?